# FTP to FTP with linux batch or command line

Tags: php, ftp

I am currently facing a rather limited shared web host that I have to (read: want to) work with to transfer files from FTP to FTP.

Server1: A dedicated linux server, full control (SSH etc.).
Server2: A limited shared web host, but FTP enabled.
Server3: A very limited shared web host, but also FTP enabled.

What I need to get done is copy files from Server2 to Server3. Server 3 has nearly all PHP file transfer options disabled, but FTP enabled. My only option is to transfer the files using FTP. The first thing that springs to mind is;

-Server1 imports files from server2 using wget (with php exec):

> exec('wget ftp://user:pass@server2.com//home/filesfolder/thefile.php
>   -P /var/www/holdingfolder');

-Server1 uploads the file to server3 using FTP and removes it from "holdingfolder"

This works, but this option is just a waste of bandwidth and assumes that server1 at all times has enough space available to hold the file until it's transferred. Can't I just FTP it directly to the other FTP server using the dedicated linux server's FTP client as a, well, puppet master?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FTP isn't intended to be a proxy system - it's point-to-point only. However, since both the ftp-only systems are webhosts, can't you install a PHP script on either server to do the server2<->server3 transfers directly? You could invoke that via wget from server1, and basically tell the other servers "ftp to the other server and fetch file X".

Comment: FTP via PHP has been disabled on server3 ;(

Comment: You could have a php script which simply serves up the contents of any file you specify. It'd be a security risk, but with appropriate password protection and some good obfuscation, the risk would be minimal.

Comment: The servers settings are hugely restricted. As you can see by this error: Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: URL file-access is disabled in the server configuration in /path/htdocs/get.php on line 4 Is there another way?

Comment: CURL's the other major one, assuming it's enabled.

Comment: Tried it, no curl allowed either. Maybe I should just give up and use the bandwidth wasting method. I'm still looking forward to possible solutions though.

Comment: The last alternative is to use raw fsockopen() and do your own stuff. But that gets rather painful quickly. A probably not-really-an-alternative is to switch hosting providers to one that's not quite as locked down, or is at least willing to punch holes in the security for specific IPs.